# Get all possible combinations of array values when repetitive values are possible

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of numbers and an array which is a subset of the first array.

**example:** `arr1 = [1,2,3], arr2 = [1,3]`

I have to get all possible combinations of `arr1` values if every value that contains in `arr2` can be repeated from 1 to 3 times.
This is the result of needed function with `arr1` and `arr2`:

```
[1,2,3], [1,1,2,3], [1,1,1,2,3], [1,2,3,3], [1,2,3,3,3], [1,1,2,3,3], [1,1,2,3,3,3], [1,1,1,3,3], [1,1,1,2,3,3,3]
```

Now I have set like this:

```
var maxRepeats = 3;

var arr1 = [1,2,3]
var arr2 = [1,3]

var result = []
var tempObject = {}

for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++){
  if (arr2.indexOf(arr1[i]) === -1){
    tempObject[i] = [];
    tempObject[i].push([arr1[i]])
  }
  else{
    tempObject[i] = [];
    for (var n = 1; n <= maxRepeats; n++){
      var currentFingerArray = []
      for (var p = 1; p <= n; p++){
        currentFingerArray.push(arr1[i])
      }
      tempObject[i].push(currentFingerArray)
    }
  }
}
```

Now `tempObject` looks like:

```
'{
  "0":[[1],[1,1],[1,1,1]],
  "1":[[2]],
  "2":[[3],[3,3],[3,3,3]]
 }'
```

But I have no idea what to do with this... Please help or steer me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate the sub counts of same values and take a recursion for getting the result.

```js
function getCombinations(values, three) {
    function iter(right, index = 0) {
        if (index === values.length) {
            result.push(right);
            return;
        }
        var sub = three.includes(values[index]) ? 3 : 1,
            temp = [];

        while (sub--) {
            temp.push(values[index]);
            iter([...right, ...temp], index + 1);
        }
    }

    var result = [];
    iter([]);    
    return result;
}

getCombinations([1, 2, 3], [1, 3]).map(a => console.log(...a));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would put the values from `tempObject` in a single array. Then they can be indexed by a single number. Then you just need to create all combinations of that number to some length. Then convert the numbers into the array elements.

Currently you have 7 elements in `tempObject`. If you put them into a single array, you can index them with a number in the range `0-6` . These become the digits, and then you just write all combinations of these digits to any length.

For example:

```
0 -> [1]
1 -> [1, 1]
2 -> [1, 1, 1]
3 -> [2]
4 -> [3]
5 -> [3, 3]
6 -> [3, 3, 3]
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

Next steps are to write a recursive function to go through all possible permutations. Consider reading about backtracking: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-possible-combinations-of-r-elements-in-a-given-array-of-size-n/

```
function getAllCombinations(dictionary, index, current, all) {
    if (Object.keys(dictionary).length == index) {
        all.push(current.slice());
        return;
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < dictionary[index].length; i++) {
        pushAll(current, dictionary[index][i]);
        getAllCombinations(dictionary, index + 1, current, all);
        popAll(current, dictionary[index][i]);
    }
}

// Push all elements from array 2 to the end of array1
function pushAll(array1, array2) {
    for (let i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
        array1.push(array2[i]);
    }
}

// Pop all elements from array1 that were added in from array 2
function popAll(array1, array2) {
    for (let i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
        array1.pop();
    }
}

res = [];
getAllCombinations(tempObject, 0, [], res);
console.log(res);
```